# .py executable file not able to find imported functions included in the script when executed, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pyinstaller, executable

I have a .py script which import some functions from an another .py script, located in an another directory in the same folder. And some of those scripts import functions from some other .py scripts contained in the folder itself.

I have created an **executable file** of my **`main.py`** file (which eventually uses functions from all other files) using **pyinstaller**. However when executed, the **.exe** application, located in the
**`./dist`** folder just **opens up and closes immediately**.

I tried to find the error by executing the file through **`cmd /K`** in **Command Prompt**, which lets the file to remain open even after executing and show errors. This is what I got :

[image]

As you can see it showed this **error** :

> **`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Static/user.txt'`**

**FYI:** This is a block of code which **reads some text** from the given **.txt** file (works fine when run through VsCode terminal), but here it fails to detect the path / locate it, Why?

The **tree of my cwd** is like this (below). The **`user.txt`** file is located inside the **`./Static`** (at bottom) and the .py script reads some text from it, which it isn't able to do now for some reason, while executed in an **`.exe`** format.

[image]

Any kind of help or suggestions would be really helpful, Thanks!

Comment: Does the file `...\hashing algorithm\dist\main\Static\user.txt` exist? It probably is inside the `src` folder.

Comment: @Kenny Hey man! I have updated my ques which the cwd tree there, do take a look, have tried to explain the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the current working directory (cwd) to define the relative path of the text file ?

If yes , remove the exe from the dist folder or put ./Static inside the dist folder.

Comment: Oh man that worked! Finally understood the error. While my terminal had the reference path to the ./Static folder, my .exe application doesn't, now by adding it obv is working fine. Thanks mate!